# How to add Google Analytics code to single page website

Tags: google-analytics

I have added Google Analytics code to many websites but this time I created a website with a single page. I would like to be able to track analytics for each part of the page, e.g. #bio, #testimonials, etc.

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Here are Google's suggestions on the topic: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications